# Lua CGI fails on call to socket

Tags: sockets, browser, lua, cgi

I have written a simple Lua script that reads from and writes to an XML database. I want to use it as CGI, eventually returning data to display in a web page, but when, for testing purposes, I go straight to the script in a browser, it blows up on require("socket.http") with a 500 Internal Server Error and it apparently can't find the Lua socket library when run in a browser.

I haven't used CGI in years and I'm very new at Lua, so thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it apparently can't find the Lua socket library when run in a browser.

I assume your script is using `socket.http`. If so, you need to make luasocket (both its binary libraries and Lua files) available to your script. My suggestion is to make it work when you run it locally, before you try to make it run as a CGI script. You'll need to either get a pre-compiled luasocket for your platform or compile and install it yourself. You'll then need to use LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH in your script to reference the locations of Lua (PATH) and binary (CPATH) files.

Comment: Paul, what a delight to have you respond! I'm using ZeroBrane Studio. For testing purposes I have the script stripped down to just 
`local http = require("socket.http")
io.write("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n", os.date(), "\n")`
just so I can call socket and see that the script executes. When run in the IDE it works fine but it fails when I run it in a browser. The full error text is in http://pastebin.com/U7CiJ75X

Comment: ;). Looking at the error message you have `socket.http` installed (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\http.lua`), but not `socket.headers` installed (`module 'socket.headers' not found`). You seem to have Lua files installed for earlier version of luasocket. You need to make sure you install all required .lua files for the version of luasocket you are using.

Comment: That was it. I don't even recall installing luasocket, but I've done so much experimenting that I'm not surprised. I put the luasocket http.lua in the path that was being searched and it worked, of course. Thank you!